# "m" changes to "mins" when page is updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, question-activity

When I open the Stack Overflow main page, all the questions have a 'last active' time. Right after the page is loaded, it will say, for example, `5m ago`. If I let the page sit until it updates the times, it will say something like `5 mins ago`. This seems pretty inconsistent. Shouldn't it just stick with `min(s)` immediately on load?

Update: The bug appears to be fixed, in that the main page displays the `m` form consistently. However, the other pages (e.g. stackoverflow.com/questions) display `min(s)`. Is there a reason for the difference? It seems inconsistent as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

**Deploy complete**