# Time suffixes (m,h) are hardcoded in the bounty section

Tags: bug, bounties, live-refresh, localization, russian-stackoverflow

If question with an open bounty has been recently updated, then you can see `m` suffix indicating minutes in the [user bounty page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971635/elfy?tab=bounties):

> [image: en-m]

After waiting a minute, timer will refresh this value automatically, and you will see `mins` instead of `m`:

> [image: en-mins]

This looks a little inconsistent. After manual update via <kbd>F5</kbd> you will see `m` again.

Same behaviuor for `hour`:

- manual load:

  > [image: en-h]
- auto refresh:

  > [image: en-hours]

I will leave testing for a `day` to developers :)

More over, string [`$minutes$m ago`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/111445080?key=8ef375ac6f9d86a1df7b2616b8aa1a13) recently added to the Transifex already translated for Russian StackOverflow and as far as I know should be used, but still doesn't. In this case looks like `м` suffix is hardcoded anywhere. E.g. bounty section in the [my profile page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=bounties):

- first load (manually):

  > [image: ru-m]
- next load (automatically):

  > [image: ru-minutes]

Comment: [Related question on ruSO.meta fixed via translation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5099/176217).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131748/m-changes-to-mins-when-page-is-updated