# Abusive post / offensive comment

Tags: discussion, flags, wording

Why when flagging a post I see "rude or abusive":

> [image: post]

But for comment similar option looks as "rude or offensive":

> [image: comment]

Should the text be different?

P.S. English is not my native language :)

Comment: Oh, it really doesn't matter. Comment flagging UI could be much better though.

Comment: Part of me wants to downvote this because "oh god, do we have to talk about the stupid comment flag dialog wording *again*...". On the other hand, I don't want to take that rage out on the OP. So -1 in spirit, 0 in reality.

Comment: @JasonC this is not stupid. If there is no reason to make them different, they should be same. This looks like duplicates in code, when you doing copy-paste, it's bad, because you can change one, and forget to fix another. Similar issue with [`m` vs `mins`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294885/339911), it's also minor and you can name it "stupid" again, but it looks ugly. Just like the current post.

Comment: @alexolut I don't think your post, or your question, is stupid at all. It's the conversations from the past that got ridiculous and the inevitable conversations (some not even directly related to your concern) that will happen here. Nothing to do with you, everything to do with my pessimism about what direction the comment conversations here are going to take. Call it a PTSD trigger. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the flag dialog  got much more love and attention, and the flag reasons were reworded several times over the years.

I'm pretty sure it was also "rude or offensive" in the beginning, and just reworded at some point to what we see now.

On the other hand, the comments flag dialog got  no attention whatsoever, the reasons were never reworded, at least not in the last few years. There is a [pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292011/drop-not-constructive-combine-noisy-reword-rude-and-other-comment-flag) asking to finally change the wording, and even remove some reasons, but as with any feature request it  might take long years to be done, if at all.